# Excel VBA paste special disjoint range from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

this is my first post to stack overflow which has already helped me **so** much - hopefully this time too. I am absolutely stuck on a simple copy paste macro. I am trying to loop through all xlsx files in a specific folder, open them one after the other and always copy the same 4 cell contents. These 4 values should be pasted to the original workbook from which the macro is running but transposed.

From what I understood, I need to use the .copy .pastespecial commands because I want to transpose and can thus not work with ranges. I also understood that the pasting needs to happen before the workbook is closed because otherwise the clipboard will be emptied upon closing of the file.

The macro correctly loops through all the files (open and closing them at the appropriate time) and also evaluates the if statement correctly. However, the .Copy does not actually seem to copy anything to the Clipboard, hence, nothing is pasted either. However, I also do not have any error messages pop up with the code below.

```
Sub Copypaste()

Dim i As Integer
Dim path As String
Dim fname As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet name")

'Define path of active excel workbook 
path = ActiveWorkbook.path
'Get list of all templates (xlsx)
templates = GetFiles(path & "\Output", "*.xlsx")
'Loop through all templates
On Error GoTo 0
For i = LBound(templates) To UBound(templates)
'First filename from list of all files in Output folder taken and opened
fname = CStr(templates(i))
Workbooks.Open Filename:=path & "\Output\" & fname
If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Copy worksheet").Range("M40") <> 0 Or _  
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Copy worksheet").Range("M45") <> 0 Or _ 
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Copy worksheet").Range("M73") <> 0 Then

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Copy worksheet").Range("F4", "M40", "M45", "M73").Copy
ws1.Range("B5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
End If
Workbooks(fname).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

Next i
End Sub
```

From what I read so far, I can only paste the values as a continuous range, can I? In an ideal case, I would paste the first 3 cell values into 3 adjacent cells and then the last value (from "M73") to another cell.

If I get this to work, I would like to expand the code such that new values which are pasted into the file do not overwrite previous values, i.e. not all pasting occurs in B5 but in the next empty row. No idea yet how to do that but that's the next problem I guess, once I get this problem sorted out with your help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `On Error GoTo 0` is masking your error.

Comment: `.Range("F4", "M40", "M45", "M73")` is incorrect syntax. For a disjoint range you should use something like `.Range("F4,M40,M45,M73")` or `Union(.Range("F4"), Union(.Range("M40"), Union(.Range("M45"), .Range("M73"))))` (though obviously the former is better because it's clearer and simpler).

Comment: @Kyle that's not how error handling works in VBA. `On Error GoTo 0` resets the error handler to the default state, which is to pass it up the stack (and if unhandled at the top, to show an infuriating little popup). I think you're thinking of `On Error Resume Next`, which hides all errors and forces manual checking/resetting of the `Err` object.

Comment: Though obviously *something* is hiding the error. I'm guessing that some error handler in the calling procedure is swallowing the error. @JS3 be aware that a call to `On Error ...` is localized within the procedure. If a sub sets `On Error Resume Next` then calls your `Copypaste` sub, your `On Error GoTo 0` isn't going to unset this error handler. The error will still bubble up to the calling sub, which will still resume next and completely ignore your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can copy disjointed ranges that are not in the same row or column. Try copying the range `F4,M40,M45,M73` in Excel to see if you get an error. My guess is that it will work for `M40,M45,M73` but not for `F4,M40`

If you are copying just those 4 cells than you can do something like

```
Set rngFrom = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Copy worksheet").Range("F4,M40,M45,M73")
Set rngTo = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet name").Range("B5:B8")

For i = 1 To 4
    rngTo(i).Value = rngFrom.Areas(i).Value ' rngTo(i) is short for rngTo.Cells(i, 1)
Next
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your help. This way, I can also copy to a disjoint range, by using the Areas property also on the rngTo! The only thing I now would like to add is copying into the next row down, i.e. not always row 5 but first row 5, then row 6, etc. Any idea how I can make rngTo dynamic in this way?

Comment: I figured it out myself by appending .Offset(k) to the rngto with k = 0 at the start and then incremented within the if loop.